# Timber, Twig: Getting Co Authors to show on author archive page

Tags: timber

Ive added the function posted_on available from the co authors site in my functions file. The regular author and co author show up on the single page but I cant seem to get it working on the author archive page. When I click the link for the co-author it goes to the correct url for the co author but the content displayed is for the regular author. I've looked at the github issues for co-authors but really confused on how to implement co authors in my twig.

im sure there is something I need for the $context but Im really unsure what to add there.

single.php

```
 <span class="author"><a href="{{post.author.link}}" rel="author"> 
     {{function('name_posted_on')}}</a>
  </span>
```

I have an author.php file

```
 $context = Timber::get_context();
 $args = 'post_type=post&numberposts=2';
 $context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts($args);

 Timber::render( array( 'author.twig'), $context );
```

In my author.twig file:

```
<div class="col-md-12">

   //I need the author or co author to be displayed in the h3 and their posts in the loop

    <h3>Latest From {{posts.author.first_name}} {{posts.author.last_name}}</h3>
</div>
{% for post in posts %}

    <article class="latest-article-widget col-md-6">
        {% block author %}


            {% if post.get_thumbnail %}
                <img src="{{post.thumbnail.src}}" class="img-responsive" />
            {% endif %}

            <div class="author">
                <span>By:</span>
                <a href="" rel="author">{{post.author.first_name}} {{post.author.last_name}}</a>
            </div>
            <h1><a href="{{post.link}}">{{post.title}}</a></h1>
            {% for item in post.get_field('post_or_page_content') %}
            <p>{{item.standard_text_content|excerpt(25)}} <a href="{{post.link}}"></a></p>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endblock %}
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s not always easily possible to integrate a plugin into Timber and Twig, because many plugins rely on The Loop, which basically only works for template files that display one single object.

Often we need to manually pass the current post’s ID to a function. For that, a function needs to have the possibility to pass the ID as a parameter. With the Co-Authors plugin, you’re in luck. There’s a `get_coauthors` function, which accepts a post ID to return all authors, including coauthors for a post. This function might not be documented, but is used internally by the plugin.

Let’s go over it step by step on how you could make this work:

**author.php**

```
<?php

$context = Timber::get_context();

$context['author'] = new \Timber\User( get_queried_object() );
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();

Timber::render( array( 'author.twig' ), $context );
```

Timber has an author functionality, but an `author` property is only set on post objects, not on archive pages. We can make use of the `get_queried_object()` function, which returns a `WP_User` object for the current post on author archive pages. We convert it to a `Timber\User` object for easier and more versatile use in the template.

For the posts, we query the default posts, without any arguments. This way, Timber uses the default for the archive page. When you pass in arguments, like you do in

```
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts( 'post_type=post&numberposts=2' );
```

then Timber will do a query just for the two arguments that you set, ignoring the query arguments set to get the authors posts. Let’s say you would access an archive for an author that has no own posts, but is only coauthor on other’s posts, then you wouldn’t see any posts in the archive for that author, because the Co-Authors plugin hooks into the default query.

To use the existing arguments and overwrite them with our own parameters to later use them in `Timber::get_posts()`, we can use [wp_parse_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_args/). We pass our new arguments as the first parameter and the query variables of the main query as the default parameters to overwrite.

```
<?php

global $wp_query;

// Set query args before posts are queried in get_context()
$args = wp_parse_args( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
), $wp_query->query_vars );

$context = Timber::get_context();

$context['author'] = new \Timber\User( get_queried_object() );
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );

Timber::render( array( 'author.twig' ), $context );
```

**author.twig**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Latest From {{ author.first_name }} {{ author.last_name }}</h3>
</div>

{% for post in posts %}
    <article class="latest-article-widget col-md-6">
        {% block author %}
            {% if post.get_thumbnail %}
                <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src }}" class="img-responsive" />
            {% endif %}

            <div class="author">
                <span>By:</span>
                {% set authors = fn('get_coauthors', post.id) %}

                {% for author in authors %}
                    {% set author = TimberUser(author) %}

                    <a href="{{ author.link }}" rel="author">
                        {{ author.first_name }} {{ author.last_name }}
                    </a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <h1><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
            {% for item in post.get_field('post_or_page_content') %}
                <p>{{ item.standard_text_content|excerpt(25) }} <a href="{{     post.link }}"></a></p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endblock %}
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Now the `get_coauthors` comes into play. Inside the for loop for each post, we can use

```
{% set authors = fn('get_coauthors', post.id) %}
```

The `fn` shorthand (or `function()`) can be used to call functions that are normally not available in Twig. We pass in the post ID of the current post to get all authors (default author plus coauthors) for that post.

Then we loop over these authors:

```
{% for author in authors %}
    {% set author = TimberUser(author) %}

    <a href="{{ author.link }}" rel="author">
        {{ author.first_name }} {{ author.last_name }}
    </a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

To be able to get the link for each author, we convert each one into a `Timber\User` object.

I hope this is what you needed.

**Small note about accessibility**

I saw that you use `<h1>` for the post titles. You’re probably trying to implement the Document Outline. While there are a lot of blogposts that show you how to do this, the [Document Outline is not implemented in any browser yet](http://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html). By still using it, you’re making it harder for users with assistive technology (like screenreaders) to read your page.

Comment: Ah yeh. I inherited this project from another dev. I assume they should of used a header element within the article element, then added the heading tag. As I understand it. Something like section>header>h1

Comment: @lnickel That wouldn’t matter. Nesting an H1 inside a header is also part of the Document Model. The solution would be to not code according to the Document Model. This basically means that you should do it like we’ve done it before. In terms of headings it means to only use one H1 per page, not skip a heading level and nest headings so that they give the page structure if you only look at the headings (like people who assistive technology do).

Comment: Bueno! Thanks for the clarification!